Details of the proof of the inequality $ \int_{X}\left(2 r \mathrm{c}_{2}(E)-(r-1) \mathrm{c}_{1}^{2}(E)\right) \wedge \omega^{n-2} \geq 0.$
I'm trying to make sense of the following proof.

Let $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle of rank $r$ on a compact hermitian manifold $(X, g)$. If $E$ admits an Hermite-Einstein structure then $$
\int_{X}\left(2 r \mathrm{c}_{2}(E)-(r-1) \mathrm{c}_{1}^{2}(E)\right) \wedge \omega^{n-2} \geq 0.
$$ Proof. The bundle $G:=\operatorname{End}(E)$ with the naturally induced connection $\nabla_{G}$ is Hermite-Einstein and has vanishing first Chern form $\mathrm{c}_{1}\left(G, \nabla_{G}\right)$. In particular, $\Lambda_{\omega} F_{\nabla_{G}}=0$. For such a bundle $G$ we will show that $\operatorname{ch}_{2}\left(G, \nabla_{G}\right) \omega^{n-2} \leq 0$ (pointwise!). Since $\operatorname{ch}_{2}(\operatorname{End}(E), \nabla)=-\left(2 r c_{2}(E, \nabla)-(r-1) \mathrm{c}_{1}^{2}(E, \nabla)\right)$, this then proves the assertion. The rest of the proof is pure linear algebra applied to the tangent space at an arbitrary point. By definition $$
\operatorname{ch}_{2}\left(G, \nabla_{G}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}\left(\left(\frac{i}{2 \pi} F_{\nabla_{G}}\right)^{2}\right)=\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{i}{2 \pi} F_{\nabla_{G}} \wedge{\overline{\left(\frac{i}{2 \pi} F_{\nabla_{G}}\right)}}^{\mathrm{t}}\right)
$$ where the expression on the right hand side is meant with respect to a local orthonormal basis. But by the Hodge-Riemann bilinear relations any matrix of primitive $(1,1)$-forms $A=\left(a_{i j}\right)$ satisfies $\operatorname{tr}\left(A \bar{A}^{\mathrm{t}}\right) \wedge \omega^{n-2}=\sum\left(a_{i j} \bar{a}_{i j}\right) \wedge \omega^{n-2} \leq 0$."

I have two questions that are not entirely clear to me. First, what do they mean by the term $\operatorname{ch}_{2}\left(G, \nabla_{G}\right) \omega^{n-2}$? Should this be $\operatorname{ch}_{2}\left(G, \nabla_{G}\right)\wedge \omega^{n-2}$ and the assertation "pointwise!" lets us multiply these in the ordinary sense?
The second question is about the Hodge-Riemann bilinear relations. I have not seen this result that any matrix of primitive $(1,1)$-forms satisfies this given inequality and even if it does, how does it apply to the proof of the proposition? It is not entirely clear how this is applied here.
